# I want to downgrade my wordpress version but i'm afraid of post data and page data will vanish?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress 4.7.1 version, also i'm using contact form 7, download moniter and email before download plugins to capture details of downloaded pdf/video files. It seems that wordpress 4.7.1 version is not compatible with this plugins; that's why I want to downgrade my wordpress version but i'm afraid of post data and page data will vanish. I never ever done this thing before, please guide me throughout!

Comment: I found this tutorial, but i'm not sure for my posts and pages will work. Thats why i havent tested it. http://dominiquej.com/how-to-downgrade-wordpress-to-previous-version/

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, try [SF] or [SU]

Comment: @pvg yes, its not programming related. but I'm asking about how to downgrade wordpress framework. Its not IT related thing.

Comment: This site is for programming-related questions so it *is* off topic, as @pvg indicated. They were just trying to be helpful by suggesting other possible places for help.

Comment: On a side note, if Wordpress have removed your plugin from their directory and are asking the developer to update it, as they are for Email Before Download, I'd be *very* wary of using it. Your site's security is far more important than recording information.

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for your suggestion, just want to ask one thing; is there any alternative solution for this? Please help me.

Comment: i mean without downgrading wordpress how can i fix this?

Comment: You's have to look for another plugin that does the same functionality, although I'm not sure if there is one or not. But in my view, having nothing to record the information is preferable to opening up your site to vulnerabilities... you could end up with no site to record information on :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you for your information. I really appreciate that. :)